# Responsive table - add row if screen to small

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, html-table

Is there any way to make this type of code as responsive?

```
<table class="resp-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-3234" src="/" />
        <p class="service-desc">XXX</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-3234" src="/" />
        <p class="service-desc">XXX</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-3234" src="/" />
        <p class="service-desc">XXX</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-3234" src="/" />
        <p class="service-desc">XXX</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-3234" src="/" />
        <p class="service-desc">XXX</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-3234" src="/" />
        <p class="service-desc">XXX</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-3234" src="/" />
        <p class="service-desc">XXX</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Currently it displays as:

```
COL1|COL2|..|COL7
```

And if possible I want to show it this way always if possible.

But if its mobile screen/small screen i want to display it row by row:

```
COL1 
COL2
.. 
COL 7
```

is it achievable with CSS only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there are two possibilities.

**Solution 1**

My suggestion is use div instead of table its simple and alternate solution.

**HTML**

```
<div class="table">
  <div class="table-cell">
    <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-3234" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
    <p class="service-desc">XXX</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table-cell">
    <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-3234" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
    <p class="service-desc">XXX</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table-cell">
    <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-3234" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
    <p class="service-desc">XXX</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table-cell">
    <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-3234" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
    <p class="service-desc">XXX</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table-cell">
    <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-3234" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
    <p class="service-desc">XXX</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table-cell">
    <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-3234" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
    <p class="service-desc">XXX</p>
  </div>
  <div class="table-cell">
    <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-3234" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
    <p class="service-desc">XXX</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  /* width:1% if you want justified table */
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .table,
  .table-cell {
    display: block
  }
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ukcp4ad9/)

**Solution 2**

If you still want to use table simply add `display:block;` to `td`

and for table heading you need to get help from `pseudo elements`

for example add `data attr` (i.e`data-th`) into `td` (i.e `data-th="some heading"`); and than add the following css

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  thead {
    display: none;
  }
  td {
    display: block;
  }
  td:before {
    content: attr(data-th);
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bmht8b24/)**

Answer (score 2):

you can force the  `table, thead,  tbody,  th,  td,  tr` to be `display`ed `block`

```css
/*General Styles */

body,
p {
  margin: 0
}
img {
  max-width: 100%
}
/* Styles for Desktops/Laptops */

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed
}
/* Styles for Mobile */

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
  table,
  thead,
  tbody,
  th,
  td,
  tr {
    display: block;
  }
  /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
  thead tr {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
  }
  tr {
    border: 1px solid red
  }
  td {
    /* Behave  like a "row" */
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid green;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 50%;
  }
  td:before {
    /* Now like a table header */
    position: absolute;
    /* Top/left values mimic padding */
    top: 6px;
    left: 6px;
    width: 45%;
    padding-right: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  /*Label the data */
  td:nth-of-type(1):before {
    content: "whatever here";
  }
  td:nth-of-type(2):before {
    content: "whatever here";
  }
  td:nth-of-type(3):before {
    content: "whatever here;

  }
  td:nth-of-type(4):before {
    content: "whatever here";
  }
  td:nth-of-type(5):before {
    content: "whatever here";
  }
  td:nth-of-type(6):before {
    content: "whatever here";
  }
  td:nth-of-type(7):before {
    content: "whatever here";
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="resp-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-3234" src="//dummyimage.com/200x200" />
        <p class="service-desc">XXX</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-3234" src="//dummyimage.com/200x200" />
        <p class="service-desc">XXX</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-3234" src="//dummyimage.com/200x200" />
        <p class="service-desc">XXX</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-3234" src="//dummyimage.com/200x200" />
        <p class="service-desc">XXX</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-3234" src="//dummyimage.com/200x200" />
        <p class="service-desc">XXX</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-3234" src="//dummyimage.com/200x200" />
        <p class="service-desc">XXX</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-3234" src="//dummyimage.com/200x200" />
        <p class="service-desc">XXX</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: might be a little bit messy with rest of the code (i bought a theme at themeforrest). Is there any way (e.g. changing tables into DIV based structure) to achieve same thing but easier? ive tried to put seven DIV's in a container but had issue with getting automatic width (to keep everything in 1 line).

Comment: You can find more info here https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap, you can write two separate tables (one of then for each purpose) and add class `visible-xs` for the mobile version and `hidden-xs` for the other one.

You can also test this just resizing your browser window.

If you want only CSS I suggest you to take these classes from bootstrap.css file.

Comment: for me its not a solution. Those classes has got a lot of dependencies thats why it will generate more issues that help.